# split pipe separated string fetched using SQL

Tags: linux, string, shell

My shell script executes a SQL to fetch the data in the following format:

```
JOB_ID_001|[PROD] This is a mail subject one ${application_date}|a@example.com,b@example.com
JOB_ID_002|[PROD] This is a mail subject two ${application_date}|c@example.com,b@example.com
```

I want to split this pipe-separated string, but the output looks very odd as follows:

```
JOB_ID_001[0]
JOB_ID_001[1]
JOB_ID_001[2]
This[0]
This[1]
This[2]
is[0]
is[1]
is[2]
a[0]
a[1]
a[2]
mail[0]
mail[1]
mail[2]
subject[0]
subject[1]
subject[2]
one[0]
one[1]
one[2]
${application_date}[0]
${application_date}[1]
${application_date}[2]
example.com,b@example.com[0]
example.com,b@example.com[1]
example.com,b@example.com[2]
JOB_ID_002[0]
JOB_ID_002[1]
JOB_ID_002[2]
This[0]
This[1]
This[2]
is[0]
is[1]
is[2]
a[0]
a[1]
a[2]
mail[0]
mail[1]
mail[2]
subject[0]
subject[1]
subject[2]
two[0]
two[1]
two[2]
${application_date}[0]
${application_date}[1]
${application_date}[2]
ple.com,b@example.com[0]
ple.com,b@example.com[1]
ple.com,b@example.com[2]
```

My desired output is:

```
JOB_ID_001
[PROD] This is a mail subject one ${application_date}
a@example.com,b@example.com
JOB_ID_002
[PROD] This is a mail subject two ${application_date}
c@example.com,b@example.com
```

So that I can continue with those strings.

My shell script is as follows:

```
email_configs=(`sqlplus -silent $DB_CONN <<-EOF
    whenever sqlerror exit 1 oserror exit oscode
    set heading off feedback off echo off verify off pagesize 0
    $sql_subject_of_mail;
    exit;
    EOF`)

for i in "${!email_configs[@]}"
do
    email_config=${email_configs[i]}

    IFS='|' read -r -a email_config_array <<< "$email_config"

    job_id=$email_config_array[0]
    subject_of_mail=$email_config_array[1]
    to_mail_id=$email_config_array[2]

    echo $job_id
    echo $subject_of_mail
    echo $to_mail_id

done
```

I checked some alternate solutions from [this](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2016/06/19/unix-split-string-using-separator/) page, but in the output ${application_date} part is missing or there is some other problem.

Can anyone have an idea about my mistake?

Comment: You forgot the curly braces: `${email_config_array[0]}`

Comment: Why are you using an array? Why not just `read -r job_id subject_of_mail to_mail_id`?

Comment: @Barmar - not working with the curly braces solution :(

Comment: Are you sure `email_configs` is being set correctly? Make sure the indentation before `EOF` is a TAB character, not spaces.

Comment: `$email_configs` is going to use spaces as the delimiters between array elements.

Comment: Yes, that's a TAB and not SPACE. I faced that problem previously.

Comment: what I found till now is using the multiple records is creating the problem. If I use `email_configs=sqlplus -silent $DB_CONN <<-EOF
 whenever sqlerror exit 1 oserror exit oscode
 set heading off feedback off echo off verify off pagesize 0
 $sql_subject_of_mail;
 exit;
 EOF` to pick up single record then its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$email_configs` array is not being set correctly. It's using spaces as the array delimiters, not newlines.

Rather than set an array, read the output of `sqlplus` in a loop.

```
while IFS='|' read -r job_id subject_of_mail to_mail_id
do
    echo "$job_id"
    echo "$subject_of_mail"
    echo "$to_mail_id"
done < <(sqlplus -silent $DB_CONN <<-EOF
    whenever sqlerror exit 1 oserror exit oscode
    set heading off feedback off echo off verify off pagesize 0
    $sql_subject_of_mail;
    exit;
    EOF 
)
```

Comment: the output looks better but still have some problem, like `${application_date}` is still `${application` in one line and `_date}` in next line.

Comment: looks like after 80 char there is a `SPACE` char automatically added, then the remaining strings.

Comment: added `linesize 30000`, and now looks like the output is ok.

Comment: That sounds like a SQL*Plus issue, not a general Linux shell scripting feature.